# unable to access class property after using access modifier?

Tags: c#

i am just learning about c#. and have learn book and some online tutorial and some blog post about access modifier.

when i am trying to write some code i am faceing some problem ==> below ...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
public class Employees
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    protected string Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public int ServiceYear { get; set; }

    void CheckEmployeePromotion(List<Employees> employees)
    {
        foreach (var employee in employees)
        {
            if (employee.ServiceYear >= 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(employee.Name + " Promoted");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class nayan
{
    Employees hasan = new Employees();
    hasan.Id = 1;
}

public class anothereclass : Employees
{
    Employees n1 = new Employees();
    n1.Id = 2;
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employees jamal = new Employees();
        jamal.Id = 23;
    }
}
}
```

after writing the above code compiler showing me some error.
[image: compiler error]

if i can create instance of Employees in my main class and access property.like ->

```
 Employees jamal = new Employees();
 jamal.Id = 23;
```

then my question why i am unable to access the property of Employees in other class (also the class with is inherit from Employees class). my question is **why** not the **solution**????

Comment: What is the error the compiler is giving?

Comment: may be you forgot to wrap it in a method/constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only set members of an instance within a method, constructor or property. So I assume you want this:

```
class Nayan
{
    Employees n1 = new Employees();

    public Nayan()
    {
        n1.Id = 2;
    }
}
```

Also consider naming-conventions, this is to name classes *PascalCase*.